# AC to DC signal to drive a MOSFET

Tags: signal, signal-processing, ac-dc, bridge-rectifier

I need to intercept a 220V AC line to drive a 3.3v MOSFET that activates (for example) an LED.

Looking around, a solution could be to use an AC/DC converter but they are meant for powering (so mostly higher current than I need) and not signals.

They are costly and inefficient for my application.

Is there an alternative way, schematics or simple /cheaper component to convert the 220V into a 3.3 V signal?

Comment: Why do you need 3.3 volts and why do you think a MOSFET would help?

Comment: More details of your project may help to get a right answer. Tranformatorless power suppliers are exist. Define the load of 3.3V power source.

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer. I would basically need to detect when AC is present . when AC is present I need a 3.3v signal .To simplify the example ( not considering the mosfet), think that this signal goes to a 3.3v volt mcu. I see also optocoupler can be alternative for this but I'm not expert with this components

Comment: Optocoupler gives galvanic isolation from primary circuit. You still need power supply for secondary circuit.

Comment: Why not use a relay?

Comment: tell the whole story as is easier: currently have a mosfet that power a 12v relay. when relay is energised it let flow ac. after relay has been energised I need to find a way to reduce relay coil power from 12v to 5v. so for this reason I'm trying to get the signal then I need to switch in some way the power rail to the relay using a double mosfet or logical switch. this is whole story

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without proper galvanic isolation your led is considered to be on the hazardous voltage side of your product by IEC and UL norms.

---

You may use a simple AC/DC capacitive power supply if you encapsulate your product in a UL 5V-B plastic enclosure.

The led though must stay inside the enclosure.

You should use a 5V-B plastic light pipe to see the light through the enclosure.

See this TDK tutorial titled "Everything for Capacitive Power Supplies"

https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/en/373562/tech-library/articles/applications-cases/applications-cases/everything-for-capacitive-power-supplies-from-a-single-source/1380514

---

TDK says:

Designs based on capacitive topologies are particularly suitable for power supplies in the milliwatt range. They are simple, compact and economical.